# How to test if my pingback was successful?

Tags: testing, blogs, pingback

I'm currently writing the pinging-back code of a blogging platform. Pingbacks work at localhost, but I want to test if they work when pinging a 3rd-party service.
Is there any website or any other solution which will show me once it received a pingback from me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a blog account on a free blogging service (like [blogger.com](http://www.blogger.com)) and test your pingback implementation.

Comment: I think that doesn't work. I believe those types of blogs accept trackbacks only, which differs in format from pingbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Both http://www.typepad.com/ and http://wordpress.com/ support pingbacks and can be used for free.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "pingbacktest" wordpress blog that accepts pingbacks:

http://pingbacktest.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/hello-world/

If you send a pingback with some URL that links to it, you'll get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
      <string>Pingback from http://foo to http://pingbacktest.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/hello-world/ registered. Keep the web talking! :-)</string>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```